# PHP; MySQL JOIN query on large datasets gets slower as WHERE conditions update

Tags: mysql, performance

So this might be a bit silly, but the alternative I was using is worse.  I am trying to write an excel sheet using data from my database and a PHP tool called [Box/Spout](https://github.com/box/spout). The thing is that Box/Spout reads rows one at a time, and they are not retrieved via index ( e.g. rows[10], rows[42], rows[156] )

I need to retrieve data from the database in the order the rows come out.  I have a database with a list of customers, that came in via `Import` and I have to write them into the excel spreadsheet.  They have phone numbers, emails, and an address.  Sorry for the confusion... :/  So I compiled this fairly complex query:

```
SELECT
      `Import`.`UniqueID`,
      `Import`.`RowNum`,
      `People`.`PeopleID`,
      `People`.`First`,
      `People`.`Last`,
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(',', `PhonesTable`.`Phone`, `PhonesTable`.`Type`)
          ORDER BY `PhonesTable`.`PhoneID` DESC
          SEPARATOR ';'
      ) AS `Phones`,
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(',', `EmailsTable`.`Email`)
          ORDER BY `EmailsTable`.`EmailID` DESC
          SEPARATOR ';'
      ) AS `Emails`,
      `Properties`.`Address1`,
      `Properties`.`city`,
      `Properties`.`state`,
      `Properties`.`PostalCode5`,
      ...(17 more `People` Columns)...,
      FROM `T_Import` AS `Import`
      LEFT JOIN `T_CustomerStorageJoin` AS `CustomerJoin` 
        ON `Import`.`UniqueID` = `CustomerJoin`.`ImportID`
      LEFT JOIN `T_People` AS `People` 
        ON `CustomerJoin`.`PersID`=`People`.`PeopleID`
      LEFT JOIN `T_JoinPeopleIDPhoneID` AS `PeIDPhID` 
        ON `People`.`PeopleID` = `PeIDPhID`.`PeopleID`
      LEFT JOIN `T_Phone` AS `PhonesTable` 
        ON `PeIDPhID`.`PhoneID`=`PhonesTable`.`PhoneID`
      LEFT JOIN `T_JoinPeopleIDEmailID` AS `PeIDEmID` 
        ON `People`.`PeopleID` = `PeIDEmID`.`PeopleID`
      LEFT JOIN `T_Email` AS `EmailsTable` 
        ON `PeIDEmID`.`EmailID`=`EmailsTable`.`EmailID`
      LEFT JOIN `T_JoinPeopleIDPropertyID` AS `PeIDPrID` 
        ON `People`.`PeopleID` = `PeIDPrID`.`PeopleID` 
        AND `PeIDPrID`.`PropertyCP`='CurrentImported'
      LEFT JOIN `T_Property` AS `Properties` 
        ON `PeIDPrID`.`PropertyID`=`Properties`.`PropertyID`
      WHERE `Import`.`CustomerCollectionID`=$ccID
        AND `RowNum` >= $rnOffset 
        AND `RowNum` < $rnLimit 
      GROUP BY `RowNum`;
```

So I have indexes on every `ON` segment, and the `WHERE` segment.  When `RowNumber` is like around 0->2500 in value, the query runs great and executes within a couple seconds.  But it seems like the query execution time exponentially multiplies the larger RowNumber gets.

I have an `EXPLAIN` here: and at pastebin( https://pastebin.com/PksYB4n2 )

```
id  select_type table         partitions  type    possible_keys                     key                   key_len   ref                                          rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE      Import        NULL        ref     CustomerCollectionID,RowNumIndex  CustomerCollectionID  4         const                                        48108   8.74        Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort;
1   SIMPLE      CustomerJoin  NULL        ref     ImportID                          ImportID              4         MyDatabase.Import.UniqueID                       1   100         NULL
1   SIMPLE      People        NULL        eq_ref  PRIMARY,PeopleID                  PRIMARY               4         MyDatabase.CustomerJoin.PersID                   1   100         NULL
1   SIMPLE      PeIDPhID      NULL        ref     PeopleID                          PeopleID              5         MyDatabase.People.PeopleID                       8   100         NULL
1   SIMPLE      PhonesTable   NULL        eq_ref  PRIMARY,PhoneID,PhoneID_2         PRIMARY               4         MyDatabase.PeIDPhID.PhoneID                      1   100         NULL
1   SIMPLE      PeIDEmID      NULL        ref     PeopleID                          PeopleID              5         MyDatabase.People.PeopleID                       5   100         NULL
1   SIMPLE      EmailsTable   NULL        eq_ref  PRIMARY,EmailID,DupeDeleteSelect  PRIMARY               4         MyDatabase.PeIDEmID.EmailID                      1   100         NULL
1   SIMPLE      PeIDPrID      NULL        ref     PeopleMSCP,PeopleID,PropertyCP    PeopleMSCP            5         MyDatabase.People.PeopleID                       4   100         Using where
1   SIMPLE      Properties    NULL        eq_ref  PRIMARY,PropertyID                PRIMARY               4         MyDatabase.PeIDPrID.PropertyID                   1   100         NULL
```

I apologize if the formatting is absolutely terrible.  I'm not sure what good formatting looks like so I may have jumbled it a bit on accident, plus the tabs got screwed up.

What I want to know is how to speed up the query time.  The databases are very large, like in the 10s of millions of rows.  And they aren't always like this as our tables are constantly changing, however I would like to be able to handle it when they are.

I tried using LIMIT 2000, 1000 for example, but I know that it's less efficient than using an indexed column.  So I switched over to RowNumber.  I feel like this was a good decision, but it seems like MySQL is still looping every single row before the offset variable which kind of defeats the purpose of my index... I think?  I'm not sure.  I also basically split this particular query into about 10 singular queries, and ran them one by one, for each row of the excel file.  It takes a LONG time...  TOO LONG.   This is fast, but, obviously I'm having a problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thank you ahead of time.  I'm sorry again for my lack of post organization.

Comment: Which table is `column1` in??

Comment: I removed the PHP tag as this is strictly a MySQL question, but from what I can see of the package it is only concerned with reading and writing spreadsheets, not reading from databases. So any problems with "[reading] rows one at a time" would seem to come from other code that you've written.

Comment: @RickJames Sorry, I know I jumbled this pretty bad.  It's T8.  I edited the query in my code and the question.

Comment: @miken32 You are correct, sorry for including the PHP tag, I was thinking about what languages I was using and PHP is one of them.  Thank you.

Comment: @Pixelknight1398 - I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The order of the columns in an index matters.  The order of the clauses in `WHERE` does not matter (usually).
- `INDEX(a), INDEX(b)` is *not* the same as the "composite" `INDEX(a,b)`.  I deliberately made composite indexes where they seemed useful.
- `INDEX(a,b)` and `INDEX(b,a)` are not interchangeable unless both `a` and `b` are tested with `=`.  (Plus a few exceptions.)
- A "covering" index is one where *all* the columns for the one table are found in the one index.  This sometimes provides an extra performance boost.  Some of my recommended indexes are "covering".  It implies that only the *index* BTree need be accessed, not also the *data* BTree; this is where it picks up some speed.
- In `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` a "covering" index is indicated by "Using index" (which is not the same as "Using index condition").  (Your Explain shows no covering indexes currently.)
- An index 'should not' have more than 5 columns.  (This is not a hard and fast rule.)  `T5`'s index had f5 columns to be covering; it was not practical to make a covering index for `T2`.

When `JOINing`, the order of the tables does not matter; the Optimizer is free to shuffle them around.  However, these "rules" apply:

- A `LEFT JOIN` *may* force ordering of the tables.  (I think it does in this case.)  (I ordered the columns based on what I think the Optimizer wants; there may be some flexibility.)
- The `WHERE` clause *usually* determines which table to "start with".  (You test on `T1` only, so obviously it will start with T1.
- The "next table" to be referenced (via NLJ - Nested Loop Join) is determined by a variety of things.  (In your case it is pretty obvious -- namely the `ON` column(s).)

More on indexing: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

**Revised Query**

```
1. Import:  (CustomerCollectionID,  -- '=' comes first
             RowNum,                -- 'range'
             UniqueID)              -- 'covering'
    Import shows up in WHERE, so is first in Explain; Also due to LEFTs
Properties:  (PropertyID)   -- is that the PK?
PeIDPrID:  (PropertyCP, PeopleID, PropertyID)
3. People:  (PeopleID)
    I assume that is the `PRIMARY KEY`?  (Too many for "covering")
    (Since `People` leads to 3 other table; I won't number the rest.)
EmailsTable:  (EmailID, Email)
PeIDEmID:  (PeopleID,    -- JOIN from People
            EmailID)     -- covering
PhonesTable:  (PhoneID, Type, Phone)
PeIDPhID:  (PeopleID, PhoneID)
2. CustomerJoin:  (ImportID,   -- coming from `Import` (see ON...)
                   PersID)     -- covering
```

After adding those, I expect *most* lines of `EXPLAIN` to say `Using index`.

The lack of at least a composite index on `Import` is the main problem leading to your performance complaint.

**Bad GROUP BY**

When there is a `GROUP BY` that does not include all the non-aggregated columns that are not directly dependent on the group by column(s), you get random values for the extras.  I see from the `EXPLAIN` ("Rows") that several tables *probably* have multiple rows.  You really ought to think about the garbage being generated by this query.

Curiously, Phones and Emails are feed into `GROUP_CONCAT()`, thereby avoiding the above issue, but the "Rows" is only 1.

(Read about `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`; it might explain the issue better.)

Comment: I made a terrible mistake in renaming the column names inconsistently as I can hardly understand my own question.  I have indexes on all of the table columns listed in the `ON` sections, as well as the `WHERE` section of the query.  Mostly because I thought this was where it would be important.  I am curious how an index on f, d, and c would change anything?  There is also an index that I added to column1 that I didn't have before but it didn't create a significant difference in query time.  I am using `LEFT` because I need the entire row to exist even if data doesn't.  Strict formatting.

Comment: @Pixelknight1398 - I added some more "rules" that I used to create my `INDEXes`.

Comment: Okay thank you I appreciate your time.  I understand what you mean by covering index, as well as composite indexes.  I try to use composite indexes for large, important queries such as this one.  My main question is, why include `SELECT` values as indexes?  And two things to mention.  One, is that I REALLY screwed up by trying to conceal the information in the query.  SO I am going to work on editing it, AND the question.  That may change your index recommendations.  Due to heavy inserting processes, indexes are need be of high value.

Comment: I have updated the question, both with the actual query, and a better formatted explain including a pastebin.  Would you by any chance be willing to reiterate your indexes with this?  I apologize for being a giant idiot.  Additionally I bookmarked your cookbook.  Thank you.  I had another MySQL helper months back recommend your webpage and I can't believe you are "the" Rick.  Now I am ultimately embarrassed....

Comment: I forgot to include in my last comments, is `LEFT JOIN` the only option for showing all rows regardless of if data is available or not?  I used `JOIN` only and I only got 80% of the rows I needed.  I understand `LEFT` might be restricting.  Do you have suggestions?

Comment: @Pixelknight1398 - I added to my Answer in the "covering" area.  `LEFT JOIN` -- OK; If you want `NULLs`.  (I find that a lot of people fail to understand left versus not left.  And it does have some impact on `INDEX` choice.)  I'll check out the revised query.

Comment: @Pixelknight1398 - I should be embarrassed -- It sounds like my cookbook was not clear enough.

Comment: @Pixelknight1398 - Revised query has been turned into `INDEXes` (mostly).

Comment: My takeaway is that I need to add an index for each group of `()`.. e.g. a composite index for `(CustomerCollectionID, RowNum, UniqueID)`?

Many tables do have multiple rows, e.g. multiple addresses, phones, and emails, for each customer.  The group concat is in use for fitting all the phones/emails for one person into one column, rather than querying many rows and looping them into a string.  I will read about `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.  Also your cookbook is great, I am just not skilled or I was fully inadequate at the time.

Comment: @Pixelknight1398 - Correct; `ALTER TABLE .. ADD INDEX(...)` for each of my suggestions.  Don't feel alone; indexing is mysterious to most people.  It took me years to bring together several concepts to write that cookbook.

Comment: I've added all of these indexes.  ``PropertyCP`` belongs to `PeIDPrID`, so should I add an index to that one?  Sorry for not including it, I had lost it between edits and it's now in my original question.  `PropertyID` and `PeopleID` are both PKs.  Additionally, most of the `EXPLAIN` rows now have `Using Where`, rather than `Using Index`.  Is this wrong?  The tables that have `NULL` still are `People, Properties, EmailsTable, PhonesTable`

Comment: @Pixelknight1398 - I added an index recommendation for PeIDPrID.  The two PKs --  The PK should be sufficient; no extra index needed.

Comment: @Pixelknight1398 - When I recommend `(a,b,c)`, I want you to add a single "composite" index: `ALTER TABLE .. ADD INDEX(a,b,c)`, not 3 separate indexes.

Comment: Definitely.  well so far it seems like the query time has gone down to about 40 seconds to execute, and 120 seconds to fetch it at most using mysql workbench.  This is good news.  Though not 10 seconds, it is a very large margin of improvement and I am very appreciative.  Some of the queries are 10 seconds or less and some are 40, not quite sure why but it works. :D

Comment: I tested the query live and it turns a 2 hour process into about 2 minutes SO.  HECK YEAH!!!

Comment: @Pixelknight1398 - Let's see the latest `EXPLAIN`, maybe I missed something.  40 seconds seems excessive for what I see.

Comment: Or am I mixing up a small test db versus a multi-mega-row production system?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure.  So the `explain` isn't showing `Using Index` anymore, however in production on a (I think?) sized down database it runs perfectly.  Seconds for each query.  Reason I say I think is because I am not in the loop as to what happens to data in the database so I don't know if it's full of data or not. Either way it's still functioning well.  In MySQL workbench, the query takes about 10 seconds to execute and in PHP I can generate my excel sheet in less than 2 minutes.  I'm gonna mess with it and edit the question for the new `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: I have 2 more massive queries that take a few hours to produce results so I am going to use your cookbook and see what I can make with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207950/discussion-between-pixelknight1398-and-rick-james).

Answer (score 1):

(I'm listing this as a separate Answer since it is orthogonal to my other Answer.)

I call this the "explode-implode" syndrome.  The query does a `JOIN`, getting a bunch of rows, thereby generating several rows, and puts multiple rows into an intermediate table.  Then the `GROUP BY` implodes back to down to the original set of rows.

Let me focus on a portion of the query that could be reformulated to provide a performance improvement:

```
SELECT ...
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(',', `EmailsTable`.`Email`)
          ORDER BY `EmailsTable`.`EmailID` DESC
          SEPARATOR ';'
      ) AS `Emails`,
      ...
    FROM ...
      LEFT JOIN `T_Email` AS `EmailsTable` 
        ON `PeIDEmID`.`EmailID`=`EmailsTable`.`EmailID`
      ...
    GROUP BY `RowNum`;
```

Instead, move the table and aggregation function into a subquery

```
SELECT ...
      ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
                DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(',', `Email`)
                    ORDER BY `EmailID` DESC
                    SEPARATOR ';' )
            FROM T_Email
            WHERE `PeIDEmID`.`EmailID` = `EmailID`
      ) AS `Emails`,
      ...
   FROM ...
      -- and Remove:  LEFT JOIN `T_Email` ON ...
      ...
      -- and possibly Remove:  GROUP BY ...;
```

Ditto for `PhonesTable`.

(It is unclear whether the `GROUP BY` can be removed; other things may need it.)

Comment: Ahh I didn't even know this was possible! lol...  Good thinking!  I'll be sure to implement this. Thank you.

Comment: I wish I could mark both of these as answers/helpful

Comment: Quick question on this answer.  The first example will give me a string like "email;email;email;".  While the second only shows "email;"  This is of course for conditions that allow for more than one email.  i don't understand why this is the case but it is...  I am going to break it down further and see if I did something wrong. The same can be said for the phones.

Comment: Hmmm... Check that `DISTINCT` was right inside `GROUP_CONCAT(...)`.

Comment: It is. The same result occurs whether it exists or not. To help, I basically copied and pasted your code and then just translated for phones.

Comment: @Pixelknight1398 - Which should it be?  `Email` or `EmailID`.  I seem to have a mixture.  I copied from your original code; not it does not make sense to have `CONCAT_WS` for emails, though it does make sense for Phones.

Comment: `(SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(
  DISTINCT 'Phone'
                ORDER BY 'PeIDPhID'.'Rank' DESC
                SEPARATOR ';')
 FROM 'T_Phone'
        WHERE 'PeIDPhID'.'PhoneID'='PhoneID'
 ) AS 'Phones',`

I have been messing around with it.  Unfortunately i've run into another problem with this query.  I need to `ORDER BY 'PeIDPhID'.'Rank' DESC` as well.

All in all it still only shows one phone number, where as before it has 5-10 :(

P.S. Sorry for terrible formatting in comment.

Comment: @Pixelknight1398 - First, some syntax issues...  Change some apostrophes to backtics.

Comment: Definitely.  Sorry habit I was worried it wouldnt format correctly.  In real its using backticks.